# Force AVG to return 0 instead of NULL when preforming on an empty set in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables called Reviews and Levels.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reviews](
    [ReviewID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Rating] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LevelID] [int] NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Levels](
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Blocks] [char](960) NOT NULL,
    [LevelID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

I want to be able to select basically the Levels table with an extra column which would be the average of all the reviews associated with that LevelID. I currently have this code

```
SELECT   AVG(Rating) AS Average, Name,Levels.LevelID,Blocks
FROM     Reviews, Levels
WHERE    Levels.LevelID = Reviews.LevelID
GROUP BY Levels.LevelID, Name, Blocks
```

This returns the correct results for the levels that have at least one review. I want to be able to return levels that have no review as well and just give an average rating of 0.

Comment: You need to use an OUTER join, which isn't supported using the ANSI-89 syntax your query uses.  Use ANSI-92 syntax...

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean about ANSI syntax but I got it working using OUTER JOIN. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this query...it'll definately solve your problem....

```
SELECT ISNULL(AVG(Rating),0) AS Average, Name,Levels.LevelID,Blocks
FROM Levels LEFT JOIN Reviews
ON Levels.LevelID = Reviews.LevelID
GROUP BY Levels.LevelID, Name, Blocks
```

Comment: After being told to use the outer join, what you have there is the exact same as what I used.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   AVG(Rating) AS Average, Name, Levels.LevelID, Blocks
FROM     Reviews, Levels
WHERE    Levels.LevelID = Reviews.LevelID
GROUP BY Levels.LevelID, Name, Blocks
UNION
SELECT   0 AS Average, Name, LevelID, Blocks
FROM     Levels
WHERE    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT   * 
                      FROM     Reviews
                      WHERE    Levels.LevelID = Reviews.LevelID );
```